# How to modulate a sound in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, pitch, pitch-shifting

I'm writing a program which generates a pure tone from a frequency inputed from the user (and this part of the program works), and which is able to produce, given an another frequency, a sound based on a sampled clarinet sound (only that sample, using its fundamentals and its harmonics).
I thought to use a table lookup, but i don't know how to apply it in MATLAB and i haven't found examples applied to the sound.
I know there was a simular question here

[changing the pitch of an audio wav file in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299974/changing-the-pitch-of-an-audio-wav-file-in-matlab)

but it is not what exactly i want to do.
Thank you for your help.

```
 %function 
 function y = analyse()
  prompt = 'Which frequency would you like to reproduce?';

 Freq = input(prompt)
 [audioIn,fs] = audioread('Si_lae.wav');
 [pitchValue,analyse] = pitch(audioIn,fs);


 amp=1;
 Fs=80000; % Fs=sampling frequency 
 duration=8;
 values=0:1/Fs:duration;
 a=amp*sin(2*pi*Freq*values);
 sound(a,Fs) 


  [Y,Fs]=audioread('Si_lae.wav'); 

 %Pitch shift
if pitchValue ~= 0
[N,D] = rat(8^(-0.4*pitchValue));
y = resample(y,N,D);    
 end

 end
```

Comment: `upfirdn` is good when you need to resample but have more control over antialiasing than with the `resample` function.

Comment: Yes, but i have to produce an another sound, not to simple change the sampling rate.