# Best way for pitch shift in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, pitch, pitch-shifting

I'm writing a program which, with a given value prompted from the user, changes the pitch of a whole track, for example if the user wants to double the fundamental the program should produce a track an upper octave (example, from A4 to A5).
I have tried this

[changing the pitch of an audio wav file in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299974/changing-the-pitch-of-an-audio-wav-file-in-matlab)

and this

[MATLAB - Pitch Shifting an Audio Signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076218/matlab-pitch-shifting-an-audio-signal)

But nothing worked. 
The commented part is my test to use the second algorythm, but it doesn't compile.

Here is my code.

```
 [audioIn,fs] = audioread('Silae.wav');
 [f0,idx] = pitch(audioIn,fs);

 subplot(2,1,1)
 plot(audioIn)
 ylabel('Amplitude')

 subplot(2,1,2)
 plot(idx,f0)
 ylabel('Pitch (Hz)')
 xlabel('Sample Number')

 %audiowrite('Silae.wav',2*fs,'trasposed.wav')   2+fs is the given ratio
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you read [the help for `audiowrite`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html)?

Comment: You say "it doesn't compile"? What does that mean exactly? It would be helpful if you posted the error message you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, i have.                                                                                                  ERROR CODE:                                                                  
Error in (line 13)
audiowrite('Silae.wav',2*fs,'trasposto.wav'),  and i don't know how to plot the result.

Comment: Can you explain what happen when you say "But nothing worked".

Comment: None of these solution compiled.

Comment: Please read this article, it should work: [A Phase Vocoder in Matlab](https://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/pvoc/)

Comment: Thanks for linking, but when i try to read a file it gives me this error: Invalid use of operator.